# Layout for a chat interface

Tags: android, android-layout

I use a LinearLayout in order to have a UI that behaves like a chat interface (it means that, at the bottom, I have an multiline EditText and a Button (to send the message) and above it, a listview that shows the messages).

The ListView is supposed to occupy the free space left by the EditText and the Button.

Right now, I have a vertical LinearLayout that contains a FrameLayout (which contains the ListViewes, I display only one ListView at the same time) and a RelativeLayout (which contains the EditText and the Button).
I have put weight on my FrameLayout and my RelativeLayout to be sure that the Listview will occupy almost all the space.

For now, it works but the problem is that when I focus the EditText (in order to type in it), the EditText becomes very small (it displays only one line).

But I would like to have a small EditText when it is not focused (in order to display as many messages as possible in the listview) and a bigger EditText when I'm typing (to display as many lines as possible).

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="1dp"
android:paddingLeft="1dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
tools:context=".ChatActivity"
android:background="#f0f4fc"
android:weightSum="100">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="82" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" 
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="18" 
    android:background="#f0f4fc"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/enterMessageHere"
        android:minHeight="50dp" 
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="3" >

        <!-- <requestFocus />  -->
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, in a nutshell, I want to have something like the "Go SMS" interface, it would be great.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: See if this helps: [left and right alignment rows inside Listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762473/left-and-right-alignment-rows-inside-listview/17762749#17762749)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText.getLayoutParams().width= 20;
EditText.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```

When you focus your text or an onclick change the size of your edit text to what you want.must look up how to detected if edit text is focused.