# How to set the list item to the right when the message is sent?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

The problem is every item in the list are aligned to left. But, I wanted to differentiate the sent message with the incoming messages.

I have two layout files:

- [item_message_left_user.xml](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/message-align-to-right/blob/master/item_message_left_user.xml)
- [item_message_right_admin.xml](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/message-align-to-right/blob/master/item_message_right_admin.xml)

I have this `if` statement in my [MessageAdapter](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/message-align-to-right/blob/master/MessageAdapter.java) class:

```
 if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_right_admin, parent, 
 }
```

This is the screenshot of my app:

[image]

> I saw one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17762473/7004388) on Stack overflow regarding the same problem. I found a clue, but I'm
>   not able to implement it. Can anyone suggest me in doing this ? The following is the clue.
>   So, whenever a user presses on send button, his message should be on right. Incoming messages should be on left.

```
if (convertView == null) {
        if (list.get(position).getTypeOfSms().equals("send"))
            convertView     = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_left, null);
        else
            convertView     = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_right, null);
```

What should be done in order to align the sent message to the right when ever the user clicks on send button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your adapter code like this ,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {


    private static final int ROW_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    private static final int ROW_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    private List<Message> messagesList;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Message> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.messagesList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int pos) {
        return messagesList.get(pos).isDelivered() ? ROW_TYPE_LEFT : ROW_TYPE_RIGHT ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          // Gets the message that we are displaying at a position
        Message message = getItem(position);

        Log.d("TAG", "message: " + message);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            int rowType = getItemViewType(position);
            switch (rowType)
            {
                case ROW_TYPE_RIGHT:
                    convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_right_admin, parent, false);
                    break;
                case ROW_TYPE_LEFT:
                    convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message_left_user, parent, false);
                    default:
            }

        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;

        if (isPhoto) {
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                    .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(photoImageView);
        } else {
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
        }

        authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

and add `isDelivered` method in the `Message` Model.

Comment: Appreciate it. Is `isDelivered()` method returns boolean value that I should add in `Message` class?

Comment: @PC. yes OR your logic to find the status of the message

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference  at com.pc.wecare.MessageAdapter.getItemViewType(MessageAdapter.java:34)`
 I got this exception when I tried your code.
Can you please tell me where I went wrong. I updated my `Message` class as you said.

Comment: I added this method in my `Message` class -    `public boolean isDelivered(){
        return true;
    }`

Comment: Krish, now the app didn't crash but I'm able to see the same view as the above picture. No change has occured! what should be my `isDelivered()` method? what i mentioned is fine or do i need to change that ? Glad that you have time to respond my questions. @Krish

Comment: @PC. What logic is you used to identify the message is send or not? That status should return in isDelivered() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142937/discussion-between-pc-and-krish).

Comment: He is so generous and the way he was there for me till my problem got solved. Appreciate your patience and constant support! @Krish

Comment: Krish, I need your help for this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43722352/7004388) Loading images from firebase is slow.

Comment: Krish can you please come to our chat room above! i have one doubt @Krish