# Loading images from firebase is slow

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-storage

Whenever I sign in to my app. The image gets loaded slowly. It usually takes lot of time to load. 
I'm using `Glide` as a library for the Image loading in my app.

```
 Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
          .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
          .into(photoImageView);
```

This above code is used for loading the image to the `ImageView` on my UI as you can see the full image takes lot of time to load.

[image]

What could be done in order to load the images faster from Firebase
storage ?

Comment: There is no artificial delay in the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage. If you want your images to load faster: make them smaller, or be on a faster connection.

Comment: I'm on full hi-speed wifi connection this would not be a problem I suppose. I'll try making m images smaller but wouldn't be an another way of getting the images faster from firebase ?

Comment: That depends on what is causing the slowdown. You'll want to investigate where the time goes: latency, bandwidth, local processing, etc. From your current description it is hard to say anything specific.

Comment: Perhaps having a better ISP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Krish](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1180691/krish) (on StackOverflow). He suggested me to change this code

```
Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
  .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
  .into(photoImageView);
```

to this code. It is working flawlessly with the below code.

```
Glide.with(getContext())
  .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
  .asBitmap()
  .centerCrop()
  .into(new SimpleTarget < Bitmap > () {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation << ? super Bitmap > glideAnimation) {
      photoImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider revising the disk cache type.

.skipMemoryCache( false ) to specifically tell Glide to not skip the memory cache thus faster loading.Also,you can change Glide's behavior of disk caching with the .diskCacheStrategy() method.

- DiskCacheStrategy.NONE caches nothing

  DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE caches only the original full-resolution
     image. In our example above that would be the 1000x1000 pixel one

  DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT caches only the final image, after reducing
     the resolution (and possibly transformations) (default behavior)

  DiskCacheStrategy.ALL caches all versions of the image

Comment: are you using base64

Comment: not sure what the means. I'm a newbie to android development.

Comment: how did encoded, or sent your image to firebase for storage, what were the methods and procedures you followed, please enlist them here

Comment: This is how I stored the image in Firebase Storage - see [MainActivity](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/firebase-image-loading-android/blob/master/MainActivity.java)
and the [MessageAdapter](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/firebase-image-loading-android/blob/master/MessageAdapter.java) used is this.

Comment: @PC. HDid you find  a solution?

Comment: No. Not yet ! :(  @Krish

Comment: @PC. What you mean by lot of time?

Comment: from the image above as you can see they are displayed as small icons. But when i scroll down or up they are slowly loading. May be one or two that's it. Not all the images are loading perfectly. 
This is how I stored the image in Firebase Storage - see [MainActivity](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/firebase-image-loading-android/blob/master/MainActivity.java) and the [MessageAdapter](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/firebase-image-loading-android/blob/master/MessageAdapter.java) used is this.

Comment: Can you come to the chat session that we started for your previous question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143134/discussion-between-pc-and-krish).

Comment: Krish, Sorry I missed your post. I waited for you! Please reply to this when ever you are online. We'll chat in our previous chat room. would be waiting for you.  @Krish

Comment: @Krish Can you come to our previous chat room!

Comment: Yes , I am here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading from url, you can also try using inbuilt FIREBASE Image loader

```
StorageReference storageReference = //make a Reference to your Image
Glide.with(context)
       .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
       .load(storageReference)
       .into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preload images when your app starts with Glide.preload() or use built in Glide cache

Answer (score 0):

You May also Consider Using Picasso, IMHO it loads faster than Glide.